# Subclass instance to Superclass

Tags: java, inheritance

How do I create subclass objects, based on an superclass objects?

eg:

```
class Super {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

```
class Sub extends Super {
    private String lastName;

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

```
public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Super sup = new Super();
        sup.setId(1);
        sup.setName("Super");

        Sub sub = new Sub();

        System.out.println(sub.getName());
    }

}
```

How can I create a 'Sub' object with the properties of a 'Super' created earlier?

Or should I pass the properties manually, like:

```
sub.setName(sup.getName());
sub.setId(sup.getId());
```

Comment: What is your use case? Why do you need that?

Comment: @nrainer I have `FirmwareVersion` and `SoftwareVersion` classes that extends `Version`. The user can add one or more Versions into a list. So, i call `new Version()`. When user click 'Save' button he must select if it is a Firmware or Software version. Then i can call `new FirmwareVersion()` or `new SoftwareVersion()`

Comment: Ok. Then I assume that it is not possible to avoid creating the instance of ``Version``, is it? Are we talking about a web application?

Comment: Yes, in that time i don't know what type of versions it will be. So, i have to create a general version. Only later, when user selects, i can create the specific version. It's a desktop app. In first time i created an abstract version, but obviously, it must be a concrete class. Is there a solution with interface method?

Comment: Why do you need to create the general version? Can't you wait until the user selects the version?

Comment: You are right. Probably it's more easy to put the version properties like `string` on the list and later get them to create the specific version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could add a copy constructor to `Super` Class

```
public class Super {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public Super(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Super(Super other) {
        this.id = other.id;
        this.name = other.name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

and then use this constructor in Sub class

```
class Sub extends Super {
    public Sub(Super other) {
        super(other);
    }

    private String lastName;

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

and you can call

```
Sub sub = new Sub(sup);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go with creating a static method in Sub:

```
Sub.fromSuper(Super s, String last)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use apache commons

```
BeanUtils.copyProperties(toBean, fromBean);
```

I wouldn't add a method to the class itself unless its really needed on every object. BeanUtils seem appropriate as it appears like something needed only in a specific situation.

In case that you really need the behaviour on every object, than implementing a [copy constructor](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=12) is a way to go